# Spring LdapContextSource different Domain Controllers

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I have multiple domain controllers configured and want to modify user attributes of users within all domains.

My config looks like this:

```
<bean id="writeLdapContextSource"
    class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://123.12.123.3:389" />
    <property name="base" value="" />
    <property name="userDn" value="domainx\userabc" />
    <property name="password" value="secret124" />
    <property name="pooled" value="false"/>
    <property name="referral" value="follow"/>
</bean>
```

I can successfully modify users within the local domain. It's no problem.

But if I try to modify users in a different domain, I get an error message.

**Note:** the ldap service user "domainx\userabc" has the correct authorization to do modifications in all domains.

Examples:

1.) Modification of an attribute of an user in another domain

**Caused by: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C04214C, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1**

2.) Changed the configuration to use Port 3268 instead of 389

**Caused by: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 00002035: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B45, comment: Operation not allowed through GC port, data 0, v1db1**

**Note:** I'am able to modify user attributes in the local domain. So my code for modification is correct.

Snippet:

```
DirContextOperations context = writeLdapTemplate.lookupContext(ldapUser.getDistinguishedName());
context.addAttributeValue(attributeName, attributeValue);
writeLdapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
```

This works perfectly for local domain users.

Anyone has an idea what to do to be able to modify users in the other domains?

I also checked the user with LDAP Browser and he is able to see all domains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Global Catalog (port 3268) provides a read-only "snapshot" of all entries in the forest. To perform write operations on an entry you will need to bind to its respective domain on port 389.

You can use the Global Catalog to query all available domains, then dynamically create LdapTemplates for each of those domains and use them to perform your modifications.